# Xpage to show resource calendar

Tags: xpages

I would like to create a small Xpages application that can show the calendar of our conference room. My idea is to have a web browser open on the Conference Room TVs so when somebody wants to get in the conference room they will see really quick that there is a meeting scheduled in 10 min.

I have tried using this template from OpenNTF - [Link](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Calendar) but I couldn't figure out how to pull the data from my Conference room resource into the calendar.

Any other idea how I can accomplish this?

Note: Having the user check the conference room schedule on LN is not an option. They already don't like LN.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Extension Library has a calendar control. It's basically the (8.5) iNotes calendar control, so data is loaded via a REST service. There are two methods of getting the data into a REST service, depending on whether or not the view you're picking up has columns with the programmatic names that are found in a Notes Mail calendar. The documentation in the XPages Extension Library book should cover the basics but, if you need clarification on any of the content, I wrote it.

Modifying the look and feel is not likely to be easy, because it's an XPage version of an IBM-specific Dojo-based control, which is possibly also why no version has been released to use the R9 look and feel.

Alternatively, it would be feasible to build a repeat control layout. Creating a ViewEntryCollection based on a DateRange is key to getting all entries between dates.